# Android : Adding multiple edittext to a relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

In my app, I am developing the UI dynamically. In root container (`RelativeLayout`) of the Activity, I wanted to add two `EditText` boxes at a specific location (specified by left, top, height and width)  using the following method:

```
    RelativeLayout rl = new Relativelayout(this);

    EditText newEditText1 = new EditText(this);
    newEditText1.layout(0, 0, 100, 100);
    rl.addView(newEditText1);

    EditText newEditText2 = new EditText(this);
    newEditText2.layout(0, 100, 100, 100);
    rl.addView(newEditText2);
```

but still they are appearing in the same line.What am i doing wring ?

Comment: Generally you should not call layout by yourself, it is used by the system. You should specify the left and top of layout parameter, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
AbsoluteLayout rl = new Absolutelayout(this);

EditText newEditText1 = new EditText(this);
EditText newEditText2 = new EditText(this);

AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams parms1 = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(0,0,100,100);
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams parms2 = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(0,100,100,100);


rl.addView(newEditText1,parms1);
rl.addView(newEditText2,parms2);
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Absolute Layout is depreciated

Comment: @NadeemIqbal you mean deprecated : yeah it's deprecated and it works well in this case

Answer (score 0):

This is not the method you are looking for.

`layout()` is a method called by a view's parent to tell it to lay out its children within the given bounds. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Instead as Fouad points out you should create a `LayoutParams` which is an inner class of the parent layout, in this you can tell the view how it should be laid out. The `LayoutParams` is then passed to the parent in addView.

While Fouad's answer, with an `AbsoluteLayout`, is the simplest way to do what you describe, it is better practice to use layout managers like `RelativeLayout` and relative layout terms like 'below' and 'to the right of'. This will give you some good guidance around this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout newlayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
EditText edit1 = new EditText(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param1 = new   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
param1.topMargin = 0;
param1.leftMargin = 20;
edit1.setLayoutParams(param1);
newlayout.addView(edit1);

EditText edit2 = new EditText(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
param2.topMargin = 150;
param2.leftMargin = 20;
edit2.setLayoutParams(param2);
newlayout.addView(edit2);
```